# Tolerances when centering a ceiling fan

Tags: electrical, ceiling, ceiling-fan

I'd like to install a ceiling fan and there's a ceiling joist in the way causing me to be about 2" off-center. The ceiling is about 8'x10' and the recessed lights that the fan would be centered between are 75" apart, so about 35" away from the fan's canopy.

Would 2" be noticeably off-center? If so, what's a possible workaround?

Comment: This is a matter of opinion. Does it even matter if it looks off center?

Comment: An off-center ceiling fan will certainly *function* fine -- the worst that can happen is it looks a little off-center :)

Comment: Also, what sort of fan box are you using for this?

Comment: A 4-inch wide one.

Comment: @Wynne -- uh, are you talking a sidemount box? a saddle box? a pancake box?

Comment: You can get boxes that sit between joists, but then I think you'll be the other 2 inches off... I really wouldn't worry about such a small offset, though.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  I'm between the joists so a "Retrofit Ceiling Fan Saf-T-Brace"

Comment: @Wynne -- a-ha, a hanger-bar old work box

Comment: Is the attic accessible? If so, you could put 2x4 blocking between the two joists and put a box on that. If you want it to be exactly centered, you would use a shallow box (1/2 inch deep pancake box) and get the fan exactly between the two lights.

Answer (score 1):

### Take that box back and get a box that attaches to the joist

It sounds like you have the wrong box for the job -- a hanger-bar type fan box like yours is designed for putting a fan between joists, not adjacent to them.  What you want instead is a fan-rated box that mounts to the side of the joist -- ask your electrical supplier for a Raco 294 or equivalent (depicted below).

[image: Raco 294]

Comment: I must not have described it correctly. If I use one of these, it'll be 2" too far to the right. If I use the between-the-joints kind, it'll be 2" too far to the left. I basically need it centered 1.5" away from the joist.

Comment: @Wynne -- got it.  does this look like a better solution?

Comment: Yes, I looked it up when you mentioned "sidemount" before. This would actually solve the centering problem, but I have a hard time believing that this won't eventually sag.